# Modifiy the "in-call" menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, menu, call

I want to change the "in-call" menu of the iphone, adding new functions for examples, but my problem is I do not know where to start.
I mean the menu which is displayed during the call.

Does anyone have an idea what I have to look for? Is it possible to add custom functions?

Any help or hint would be great... :)

Greetings,
mathew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer .. you can't.. you can't modify any exiting iPhone app using your application.